# Hacer un between de 2 columnas codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Normalmente he realizado un between sobre una misma columna ejemplo:

```
$Where['autos.precio>=']  = 200;
$Where['autos.precio<=']  = 300;

$this->MainModel->listar('autos',$Where,'');
```

Que me traería todos los autos en un rango de precio de 200-300 esto se realiza sobre una sola columna que es "precio".

> Ahora quiero realizar un between sobre dos columnas distintas
>   "fecha_recepcion" y "fecha_venta":

Formato fecha : YYYY/MM/DD

```
$Where['autos.fecha_recepcion>=']  = "2017-08-09";
$Where['autos.fecha_venta<=']      = "2017-08-25";

$this->MainModel->listar('autos',$Where,'');
```

Necesito obtener los vehículos que están entre 2 fechas sobre dos columnas , espero haberme explicado bien saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos, lo que comprendo es que necesitas delimitar entre esos campos, lo que veo es que solo limitas una fecha a la vez, queda incompleto. prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
$Where['autos.fecha_recepcion>=']  = "2017-08-09";
$Where['autos.fecha_recepcion<=']  = "2017-08-25";
$Where['autos.fecha_venta>=']  = "2017-08-09";
$Where['autos.fecha_venta<=']  = "2017-08-25";

$this->MainModel->listar('autos',$Where,'');
```

Espero te sirva.